# Angular And Ionic Application Issue in Production build

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

**ERROR in : Type PopoverReportsPage in /home/dhwani/New Clone/metricool/src/app/pages/popover-reports/popover-reports.page.ts is part of the declarations of 2 modules: PopoverReportsPageModule in /home/dhwani/New Clone/metricool/src/app/pages/popover-reports/popover-reports.module.ts and AppModule in /home/dhwani/New Clone/metricool/src/app/app.module.ts! Please consider moving PopoverReportsPage in /home/dhwani/New Clone/metricool/src/app/pages/popover-reports/popover-reports.page.ts to a higher module that imports PopoverReportsPageModule in /home/dhwani/New Clone/metricool/src/app/pages/popover-reports/popover-reports.module.ts and AppModule in /home/dhwani/New Clone/metricool/src/app/app.module.ts. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes PopoverReportsPage in /home/dhwani/New Clone/metricool/src/app/pages/popover-reports/popover-reports.page.ts then import that NgModule in PopoverReportsPageModule in /home/dhwani/New Clone/metricool/src/app/pages/popover-reports/popover-reports.module.ts and AppModule in /home/dhwani/New Clone/metricool/src/app/app.module.ts.
: Type ProfileShowPage in /home/dhwani/New Clone/metricool/src/app/pages/profiles/profiles.page.ts is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule in /home/dhwani/New Clone/metricool/src/app/app.module.ts and ProfilesPageModule in /home/dhwani/New Clone/metricool/src/app/pages/profiles/profiles.module.ts! Please consider moving ProfileShowPage in /home/dhwani/New Clone/metricool/src/app/pages/profiles/profiles.page.ts to a higher module that imports AppModule in /home/dhwani/New Clone/metricool/src/app/app.module.ts and ProfilesPageModule in /home/dhwani/New Clone/metricool/src/app/pages/profiles/profiles.module.ts. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes ProfileShowPage in /home/dhwani/New Clone/metricool/src/app/pages/profiles/profiles.page.ts then import that NgModule in AppModule in /home/dhwani/New Clone/metricool/src/app/app.module.ts and ProfilesPageModule in /home/dhwani/New Clone/metricool/src/app/pages/profiles/profiles.module.ts.
src/app/pages/connections-page/connections-page.page.html(219,79): : Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.**

**App.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { FileTransfer } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer/ngx';
import { FileOpener } from '@ionic-native/file-opener/ngx';
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy, NavParams } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { Instagram } from "@ionic-native/instagram/ngx";
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { LayoutComponent } from './components/layout/layout.component';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import {File} from '@ionic-native/file/ngx'
import { PhotoLibrary } from "@ionic-native/photo-library/ngx";
import { AppAvailability } from "@ionic-native/app-availability/ngx";
// import { Firebase } from "@ionic-native/firebase/ngx";
import { FirebaseX } from "@ionic-native/firebase-x/ngx";
import { UniqueDeviceID } from '@ionic-native/unique-device-id/ngx';
import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device/ngx';
import { TwitterConnect } from '@ionic-native/twitter-connect/ngx';
import { Facebook } from '@ionic-native/facebook/ngx';
import { WelcomePage } from './pages/welcome/welcome.page';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';
import { DeleteAccountModalPage } from './pages/delete-account-modal/delete-account-modal.page';
import { PopoverDatePage } from './pages/popover-date/popover-date.page';
import { Splash } from "./pages/splash/splash.component";
import { PopoverReportsPage } from './pages/popover-reports/popover-reports.page';
import { Globalization } from '@ionic-native/globalization/ngx';
import { ProfileShowPage } from './pages/profiles/profiles.page';
import { CreateNewPostPage } from './pages/create-new-post/create-new-post.page';
import { PopoverReportsPageModule } from './pages/popover-reports/popover-reports.module';

export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyDDVrXtXhTO60cYivkRwaU5XoM0CnrMyOI",
  authDomain: "metricool-cc74e.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://metricool-cc74e.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "metricool-cc74e",
  storageBucket: "metricool-cc74e.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "352613795929"
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LayoutComponent,
    WelcomePage,
    DeleteAccountModalPage,
    PopoverDatePage,
    PopoverReportsPage,
    ProfileShowPage,
    Splash
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    DeleteAccountModalPage,
    PopoverDatePage,
    PopoverReportsPage,

    ProfileShowPage
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule, 
    PopoverReportsPageModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFirestoreModule,

    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    Globalization,
    SplashScreen,
    FirebaseX,

    File,FileOpener,FileTransfer,
    UniqueDeviceID,
    Device,
    Instagram,
    PhotoLibrary,
    AppAvailability,
    TwitterConnect,
    Facebook,
    InAppBrowser,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
  ],
  //exports:[PopoverReportsPage],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }


export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}
```

**PopoverReportsPageModule.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { PopoverReportsPage } from './popover-reports.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: PopoverReportsPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [PopoverReportsPage]
})
export class PopoverReportsPageModule {}
```

What I have to do in this I dont understand can any one help me to solve this issue??

Answer (score 0):

Create a new module give it name like SharedModule or something else. Then import your popover module into SharedModule and wherever you want popover import  SharedModule in that page module.